# Are nail pops under vinyl flooring likely to worsen?

Tags: flooring

I have been in my new Mobile home now for 5 months.Nails are starting to pop up slightly under the linoleum floor. Is this likely to get worse over time?

Comment: To me, that sounds like a warranty defect.  I would first start with the dealer and then the manufacture to get it fixed.

Comment: I would guess that Your house is not properely supported. There are some tensions that bend the floor when some load occur and then relax if it is off.

Answer (score 1):

It will certainly worsen. The nails are probably coming up because the subfloor was not glued to the framing. Not only will more nails work up, but the vinyl will very quickly wear through in those spots.

I agree that this is certainly a warranty issue. If you're not able to get satisfaction from that, you'll need to re-fasten the subfloor and reinstall flooring. I'd probably run suitable screws at 12" intervals on all joists, then fill the dimples and overlay new vinyl. An embossing leveler may be necessary to flatten the texture of the current vinyl.

Comment: It sure ain't gonna get any better all by itself. Plus one.

Answer (score 0):

It has a possibility of getting worse or the popping could be done.  It's hard to say one way or the other.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely get the foundation checked-out & call for warranty service. A framing member may have been damaged/defective or there may be a temporary support that was left in place instead of removed or the foundation is contacting the wrong area or not contacting enough areas.